# In Ansible, how do I setup dictionaries with lists?

Tags: ansible

Say I want to use the FlatKey.firewalld playbook from Ansible galaxy, and it has thei task for setting up firewall port rules

```
- name: set firewalld port rules
  firewalld: 
    port={{item.value.port}}/{{item.value.protocol|default('tcp')}
    permanent={{item.value.permanent|default('true')}
    immediate={{item.value.immediate|default('true')}
    state={{item.value.state|default('enabled')}
    zone={{item.value.zone|default('public')}}
  with_dict: "{{firewalld_port_rules|default({})}}"
```

I have a defaults/main.yml file setup up this way

```
firewalld_port_rules:
  key:
    port: 123456
    protocol: tcp
    state: enabled
    zone: public
    permanent: true
    immediate: true
```

How can I use this for multiple ports, without repeating code? IOW I really want something like this, but of course the syntax does not work. Hopefully, you get the idea.

```
firewalld_port_rules:
  key:
    port: [123456, 45678, 45679]
    protocol: tcp
    state: enabled
    zone: public
    permanent: true
    immediate: true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with [looping over subelements](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_loops.html#looping-over-subelements):

> Subelements walks a list of hashes (aka dictionaries) and then traverses a list with a given (nested sub-)key inside of those records.

You'd need fork the playbook and change the task to:

```
- name: set firewalld port rules
  firewalld:
    port: "{{item.1}}/{{item.0.protocol|default('tcp')}}"
    permanent: "{{item.0.permanent|default('true')}}"
    immediate: "{{item.0.immediate|default('true')}}"
    state: "{{item.0.state|default('enabled')}}"
    zone: "{{item.0.zone|default('public')}}"
  with_subelements:
    - "{{firewalld_port_rules|default({})}}"
    - port
```

Comment: This works when all data identically except one column (`port` in question), but solution is not flexible. Example: if you need 123 permanent tcp and 234 udp non permanent.

Answer (score 0):

Use `with_items` instead of `with_dict`:

```
- name: so question 552716
  hosts: '{{ target }}'
  vars:
    firewalld_port_rules:
      - { port: 123
        , state: enabled
        , zone: public
        , permanent: true
        , immediate: true
        , protocol: tcp }
      - { port: 222
        , state: enabled
        , immediate: true
        , protocol: udp }
      - { port: 333
        , state: enabled
        , zone: public
        , permanent: true
        , immediate: true
        , protocol: tcp }
  tasks:
    - name: show debug
      debug: msg="port = {{ item.port }} , state = {{ item.state }}, zone = {{ item.zone | default('public') }}, permanent = {{ item.permanent | default(true) }}"
      with_items: "{{ firewalld_port_rules }}"
```

Note, that permanent is always true and zone is public usually, so you can omit them and use default value (see port 222 for example).

See additional link also: [Standard Loops](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_loops.html#standard-loops)